# Load edit form Checkboxes with data from API - Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, typescript, api, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to fill checkbox with values from an API when a form is in edit mode. 
 when I hard code the values of checkbox it is working [stackblitz working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-table-for-student-data-in-angular-isg8jh), but when I load the data from the service through http request, I got the following error in console. also i attached the  [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-table-for-student-data-in-angular-ysackm) that has the error
[image]

Comment: Initializing the FormGroup would fix it: `myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});`. optional chaining the array would fix the second error: `*ngFor="let rentPeriod of rentPeriodsArr?.controls; index as i"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I forgot to use *ngIf.  I corrected the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-table-for-student-data-in-angular-ysackm)

In the component html template file, Just wrap the form inside a `**<div *ngIf="rentPeriodList">**`

```
<div *ngIf="rentPeriodList">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <label
      formArrayName="rentPeriods"
      *ngFor="let rentPeriod of rentPeriodsArr.controls; index as i"
    >
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" />
      {{ rentPeriodList[i].name }}
    </label>

    <button>submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```